# How to solve for angle $a_1$ in this diagram?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The two horizontal lines are parallel. Angles $a$ and $b$, and lengths $x$ and $y$ are known. How can I solve for $a_1$ (or $a_2$)?

[image]

Thank you for your help. I'll provide the context for this below. I'm interested in knowing the effective seat tube angle $a_1$ on a bicycle given a known seat tube angle $a$ ($a_1 + a_2$), seat post height $y$, and seat post setback $x$.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you considered the cosine rule to find the other length of the triangle which has 2 lengths of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Note that $\tan a_1=\frac{y}{x\sin a}$

Comment: @Vasya could you provide a proof of this? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve without law of sines and cosines, draw perpendicular from points on the top. Now using trigonometry,

[image]

$BF = y \cos a$ $(\angle a_1 + \angle a_2 = \angle a)$

$CA = EF = y \sin a$

Now using the $\triangle ABC$, $ AB = x + y\cos a $

So, $\tan a_1 = \frac {y \sin a} {x + y\cos a} \implies \angle a_1 = tan^{-1} (\frac {y \sin a} {x + y\cos a})$

$ \angle a_2 = \angle a - \angle a_1$.

Comment: Thanks, this is a lovely solution

Answer (score 1):

We can proceed as follows

- find the third length $z$ by [law of cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)

$$z^2=x^2+y^2-2xy \cos b$$

- use [law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) to find $a_2$

$$\frac{\sin a_2}{x}=\frac{\sin b}{z}$$